# Why my chat application that does not work behind a router?

Tags: java, sockets, router

I developed a chat application Java/Socket(TCP), it works perfectly on my local network,however when i put it behind a router it does not work...
I have already tested the open ports on my router at:
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
the result is as follows

```
80 (HTTP)is open
21 (FTP)is open
22 (SSH)22 is open 
23 (TELNET)is open
25 (SMTP)25 is open
.
.
.
```

I started my server with this list of ports(`java -jar server.jar 23`) :

```
    int port=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);


    System.out.println("server started at " + port);
    Socket clientSocket = null ;

    // repeatedly wait for connections, and process
    while (true) {



        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.Println("error");
        }
        System.err.println("new client connected!");


        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true);



        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println("from server: "+s);
        }

        // colse all
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
```

then Then with a simple client I tried to connect =>  anything received....

where does the problem? so how Skype,Msn and others chat application works fine?
there is a solution to do that ?

PS:I put a simple code(echo server) that represents my real server so you understand my code quickly :).

My regards .

Comment: What IP address are you trying to connect with rfom your client?

Comment: Unless your machine behind the router is running HTTP, FTP, SSH, TELNET, and SMTP servers, then your router is not doing a very good job of protecting your network.  Those ports should be closed, not opened.

Comment: @Perception : is the public address where the server is running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a server running behind a router is not enough for an outside client to establish a connection.  Whatever port the server is listening on, the router needs to have a Port Forwarding rule configured on it that forwards inbound traffic for that port to the machine the server is running on.  The client then needs to connect to the port on the router's public IP so the router can then forward that traffic to the server.

Comment: I agree with you,but how to avoid the configuration?already several software works without router configuration...

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13285/Using-UPnP-for-Programmatic-Port-Forwardings-and-N

Comment: uPNP only works if the router supports it AND if it is enabled.  And even if uPNP on the router is usable, don't forget to configure the server's firewall as well to allow inbound traffic. There is a separate API for interacting with the Windows Firewall, for instance. Typically, in a chat scenario, if one party cannot connect to the other, they usually swap roles so the conection goes in the other direction, which will then pass through the router/firewall. But if the other party is also behind a router/firewall, you usually have to use a public central server to delegate the chat messages.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, did you go into your router's configuration utility and set it up to proxy (usually called port forwarding) telnet requests to the client? Your router may be listening on 23, but unless you're running the chat client on the router's firmware, I doubt it knows what to do with that traffic. Maybe I misunderstood your question though.

Comment: this is actually a very valid concern, as just opening the ports is not enough.  His style communication only works when the traffic originates from the system to the main central server (like AIM/Yahoo...etc).  When the traffic originates externally the clients must know how to route to the device.  They know the external IP and the ports, but the router itself needs to know what to do with that traffic.